# Using jquery .hover, with $this

Tags: jquery, html

This is one of my HTML elements.

`<textarea type="text" data-class-changer="question" class="questioninputcss js-questioninput" data-integer-question="878"></textarea>`

When I hover over an element, I want that element to toggleclass

I also tried addclass and removeclass, but I'm not sure if they would have been animated  - which I need. In any case, none of my scripts have worked.

This is my mouseover script, which works and is almost identical to the first hover script which doesn't work.

```
    $(document).on("mouseover", ".questioninputcss",function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("questioninputcssHidden", 700);
    });
```

These are the many hover scripts I've tried:

```
    $(document).on("hover", ".questioninputcss",function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("questioninputcssHidden", 700);
    });


    $(document).hover(
        function(){ $(this).addClass('questioninputcssHidden') },
        function(){ $(this).removeClass('questioninputcssHidden') }
    );


    $(".js-questioninput").hover(
        function(){ $(this).addClass('questioninputcssHidden') },
        function(){ $(this).removeClass('questioninputcssHidden') }
    );



    $(".js-questioninput").hover(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("questioninputcssHidden", 700);
    });



    $(".questioninputcss").hover(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("questioninputcssHidden", 700);
    });



    $(document).hover(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("questioninputcssHidden", 700);
    });



    $(document).hover(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("questioninputcssHidden", 700);
    }, function(){
        $(this).toggleClass("questioninputcssHidden", 700);
    });
```

Comment: Probably because `".answerinputcss" !== ".questioninputcss"`?

Comment: Are you trying to toggle it on, then off each time you hover? or just toggle the class on when you are in the hover state?

Comment: @Doorknob Negative, unfortunately. I forgot to set that one back to question for posting here, but it doesn't work either. I updated my post.

Comment: Also it would be nice if you could post a fiddle so we could play with your code :)

Comment: @ajmajmajma It doesn't do either of them - I have no effects, at all. However, I want the new class to remain as long as the mouse is inside of the element, and then go back to default when the mouse leaves. So, while in hover state.

Comment: You dont need javascript for that you can just do css :hover

Comment: @ajmajmajma http://jsfiddle.net/kphq9ap2/5/ <-- oddly, this doesn't work - though it does on my site.

Comment: @ajmajmajma And keep the animation?? http://jqueryui.com/toggleClass/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/alexjm/kphq9ap2/9/

Comment: Also - it doesn't work in that fiddle because you don't have jquery loaded on it - but you will still run into problems because hover tracks both mouse enter and leave - so it will fire twice

Answer (score 1):

By what you described, all you have to do is:

```
.questioninputcss:hover {
  //your desired hover styles in here (the styles you have on answerinputcssHidden)
}
```

and add a transition to the base element if you want it animated as per your request like so

```
.questioninputcss {
transition: 1s all;
```

based on your fiddle  here is a working example of this - http://jsfiddle.net/alexjm/kphq9ap2/9/

If you want to use this, don't also you the hover() jquery method, as they will fight against each other. However if you want to use hover, if you read the documentation - the problem you are having with it is hover binds to both when the mouse enters and leaves the targeted item - see here for reference http://api.jquery.com/hover/.

So, you would do something like this -

```
   $( ".questioninputcss" ).hover(
 function() {
    $( this ).addClass("questioninputcssHidden", 700);
 }, function() {
    $( this ).removeClass("questioninputcssHidden", 700);
 }
 );
```

see here - http://jsfiddle.net/alexjm/kphq9ap2/31/

Comment: Your fiddle worked, thank you. You should consider adding the transition part of the code here, where others can see.

It does transition the same way as mouseenter, it's actually quite different - but in this case, it will work better. I gave you a +1.

Comment: it's in the fiddle :)

Comment: It is in the fiddle, but if this ends up being the best answer and I mark it as such - anyone who comes to look, will read your response and probably not the comments. They'll waste time trying to figure out why it doesn't transition. Because, you said "all I have to do" is add hover.

Comment: Darn, I just used it and the "transition" line negatively affected my jQuery animations.

Comment: @Nemo-Omen, yes you don't want to use the css method AND the javascript/jquery method together, they are both doing the same thing in a different way so they will fight against each other. You can use either method, I think the css is a little cleaner :).